# Statistics, conditional probability

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

Suppose you work for a political candidate, and you know about the probability that the candidate is viewed favorably by young and old voters. Suppose 60% of older voters intend to vote for the candidate. Furthermore, 24% of all (i.e., young and old) voters are older voters who would vote for the candidate. What is the percentage of older voters in this area?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the proportion of older voters in the population. Since $60\%$ of older voters favour your candidate, the proportion of voters who are older and favour your candidate is $(p)(0.6)$.

But we are told that this proportion is $0.24$. It follows that 
$$(p)(0.6)=0.24.$$
Now solve for $p$.